# Salvar um array byte no sql vindo de um Datatablereader

Tags: c#, array, winforms

Em uma das tarefas do sistema, preciso consultar um banco Sql Server, que me retorna um  `Datatable`, neste `Datatable`, um dos dados é do tipo `Byte[]`

Então, para ler o `Datatable` utilizo um `DataTableReader`, que me gera um `Object`, certo?

```
 async private void Upload_Ra(DataTable Dat_RaWebLocal)
    {
        DataTableReader dtr = Dat_RaWebLocal.CreateDataReader();

        if(dtr.HasRows)
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Relatorio encontrado, iniciando enviado para nuvem";

            Classes.Cadastro.Crm.Upload_RaWeb Up_RaWeb = new Classes.Cadastro.Crm.Upload_RaWeb();

            await dtr.ReadAsync();

            Up_RaWeb.Upload(Convert.ToInt32(dtr["id"]), dtr["cod_item_Crm"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(dtr["cod_cli"]), dtr["razao_social"].ToString(), Convert.ToDateTime(dtr["data_rec"])
                            , Convert.ToDateTime(dtr["data_anal"]), Convert.ToInt32(dtr["n_Crm"]), Convert.ToInt32(dtr["n_Nf"])
                            , dtr["OF_anterior"].ToString(), dtr["modelo"].ToString(), dtr["material"].ToString(), dtr["arranjo"].ToString(), dtr["diam"].ToString()
                            , dtr["tipo"].ToString(), dtr["inicio_op"].ToString()
                            , dtr["fim_op"].ToString(), dtr["motivo"].ToString(), dtr["tag"].ToString(), dtr["fabric_bomba"].ToString(), dtr["mod_bomba"].ToString()
                            , dtr["prod_fluido"].ToString(), Convert.ToDecimal(dtr["temp_fluido"])
                            , Convert.ToDecimal(dtr["rpm"]), dtr["api"].ToString(), Convert.ToDecimal(dtr["pres_suc"]), Convert.ToDecimal(dtr["pres_desc"])
                            , dtr["diag_falha"].ToString(), dtr["analise"].ToString(), dtr["conclusao"].ToString()
                            , dtr["recomend"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(dtr["nivel"]), ObjectToByteArray(dtr["bfoto1"]), "", ObjectToByteArray(dtr["bfoto2"]), ""
                            , ObjectToByteArray(dtr["bfoto3"]), "", ObjectToByteArray(dtr["bfoto4"]), "", ObjectToByteArray(dtr["bfoto5"]), "", ObjectToByteArray(dtr["bfoto6"]), "");                
        }
    }
```

Então, preciso converter esse `Object` para `Byte[]` para que possa salvar em outro servidor.

Então, pesquisando, achei a seguinte pergunta:

[Convert any object to a byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865104/convert-any-object-to-a-byte)

Então, utilizando o metodo abaixo:

```
byte[] ObjectToByteArray(object obj)
{
    if(obj == null)
        return null;
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

consegui converter o `Object` para `byte[]`, mas, notei que o mesmo mudou totalmente a cadeia de caracteres, esta certo isso?

Tem outra maneira, que eu possa recuperar esse `array` ?

Comment: O `dtr["bfoto3"]` o seu valor não é um `array de bytes` se sim não precisa converter de novo para `array de bytes` é só dar um `cast` nessa variável!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Perfeito.. Obrigado